# \paragraph command indentation depending on paragraph title

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

When using the `\paragraph{Title}` command is there a way of aligning the proceeding lines with the title of the paragraph.
Or is there any package that makes the paragraph sectioning into an environment that perhaps could align the text?

Default:
[image: default]

Indented:
[image: indented]

Comment: for the text in the image you should use `\begin{itemize}\item`  not `\paragraph`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `\paragraph`, I would suggest to type these kind of contents in a list, e.g. using `itemize`. Short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{a)}] Tegn grafen for $f$ i grafvinduet $[-5,5]\times[-5,5]$.
\item[\textbf{b)}] Bestem gradienten for $f$ i punktet $P(1,3, f$ and so on and so on and grafens stejlhed i punktet $P$.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, `itemize` automatically ensures the proper indentation of the text following the "titles" (here rather the problem numbers). Instead of manually defining the problem numbers, you can also employ the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=de) package to adjust numbering and formatting of the list environments.